# NSXMLParser and namespace elements

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using NSXMLParser to parse a Feedburner/atom feed.  I can get most elements to work however I am not sure how to parse the following:

I would like to get at and store the href from this tag.  How do I do this?

Thanks
-Tom Printy

Comment: You probably need to properly format the XML/URL your trying to include in your OP, since its coming out blank/missing.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figure it out....

In the idStartElement callback I added the code:

> if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
>   NSString
>   *string = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
>   NSLog(@"Link is %@ ", string);
>   [currentLink appendString:[self cleanURL:string]];
>   }

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
//NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        if([[attributeDict objectForKey:@"rel"] isEqualToString:@"alternate"]){
            NSString *string = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
            NSString *titulo = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSLog(@"Link is %@ ", string);
            NSLog(@"titulo is %@ ", titulo);
            //[currentLink appendString:[self cleanURL:string]];
        }
    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) {
        NSString *url = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"url is %@ ", url);
    }

}
```